SelectableText.rich in Flutter desktop deselects text after Shift + Click selection
I am working on a Flutter desktop app where I display syntax-highlighted code using SelectableText.rich with TextSpan. However, I am facing an issue when trying to select multiple lines of text by pressing Shift and clicking. The selection highlights for a second and then immediately disappears. The text becomes deselected automatically.
I have attached a video demonstrating the issue.
(https://imgur.com/a/ZMVydf6)
Below is the code I am using:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:highlight/highlight.dart' as highlight;

class CodeContentBuilder {
  static const Color _codeBackgroundColor = Color(0xFF282a36);
  final double fontSize;

  CodeContentBuilder({this.fontSize = 14.0});

  Widget buildCodeContent(String code, String language) {
    String cleanLanguage = language.replaceAll('.', '');
    final highlighted = highlight.highlight.parse(code, language: cleanLanguage);

    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      color: _codeBackgroundColor,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 12),
        child: SelectableText.rich(
          TextSpan(
            children: _convert(highlighted.nodes!),
          ),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'monospace',
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: fontSize,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<TextSpan> _convert(List<highlight.Node> nodes) {
    List<TextSpan> spans = [];
    var currentSpans = spans;
    List<List<TextSpan>> stack = [];

    void traverse(highlight.Node node) {
      if (node.value != null) {
        currentSpans.add(node.className == null
            ? TextSpan(text: node.value)
            : TextSpan(
                text: node.value, style: _getStyleForClass(node.className!)));
      } else {
        List<TextSpan> tmp = [];
        currentSpans.add(
            TextSpan(children: tmp, style: _getStyleForClass(node.className!)));
        stack.add(currentSpans);
        currentSpans = tmp;

        for (var n in node.children!) {
          traverse(n);
          if (n == node.children!.last) {
            currentSpans = stack.isEmpty ? spans : stack.removeLast();
          }
        }
      }
    }

    for (var node in nodes) {
      traverse(node);
    }

    return spans;
  }

  TextStyle _getStyleForClass(String className) {
    switch (className) {
      case 'keyword':
        return const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
      case 'string':
        return const TextStyle(color: Colors.green);
      case 'number':
        return const TextStyle(color: Colors.orange);
      case 'comment':
        return const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic);
      default:
        return const TextStyle(color: Colors.white);
    }
  }
}

class CodeDisplayWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String code;
  final String language;

  const CodeDisplayWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.code,
    required this.language,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final codeContentBuilder = CodeContentBuilder();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Code Display: $language'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: codeContentBuilder.buildCodeContent(code, language),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Code Display Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: const CodeDisplayWidget(
        code: '''
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
''',
        language: 'dart',
      ),
    );
  }
}

I’ve tried various approaches but couldn’t find a way to prevent the text from being deselected. Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution?
